# Progress bar does not updated wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I am trying to update my progress bar inside `contentrendered(object sender, EventArgs e)` event. This is my code :-

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
DynamicControls.ProgressBarWindow _progressBarWindow = new DynamicControls.ProgressBarWindow("Please Wait...");
_progressBarWindow.ShowDialog();
```

**XAML**

```
<Window x:Class="nk_Image_Converter.DynamicControls.ProgressBarWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="ProgressBarWindow" Height="100" Width="500" BorderThickness="0" WindowStyle="None" ResizeMode="NoResize" Background="#d4dce6" Loaded="Window_Loaded" Initialized="Window_Initialized" ContentRendered="Window_ContentRendered" LayoutUpdated="Window_LayoutUpdated" Activated="Window_Activated" >
<Window.Effect>
    <DropShadowEffect Opacity="0.4"/>
</Window.Effect>
<Border BorderBrush="CadetBlue" BorderThickness="3,0,3,3">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid Grid.Row="0" Background="CadetBlue"></Grid>
        <Grid Grid.Row="1" Background="Transparent">
            <Label x:Name="Message" Content="Please Wait..." Margin="42,15"/>
            <ProgressBar x:Name="Progressbar" Width="400" Height="25" Margin="47,38,47,14" Foreground="CadetBlue" BorderBrush="CadetBlue" BorderThickness="2"></ProgressBar>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Border>
```

[image: nk_Image_Converter.DynamicControls.ProgressBarWindow]

**C#**

```
private void Window_ContentRendered(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for(//Some Condition//)
        {
              Some Stuff
              Thread.sleep(100);
              this.ProgressBar.Value = //Some Value
              // above statement doesn't update the progressbar instantly

        }
    }
```

In the code above, I want the progress Bar to move as I give a Value every time
inside for loop, but it gets updated when the event get completed.

Comment: tried but not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **BackroundWorker** to update value of Progress bar as below:

```
private void Window_ContentRendered(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
    worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
    worker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(worker_DoWork);
    worker.RunWorkerAsync();
}


private void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;

    for(//Some Condition//)
    {
          //Some Stuff
          Thread.sleep(100);
          worker.ReportProgress(/*Some Value*/);

    }
}
```

**BackroundWorker** is in **System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker** namespace.

Additional information can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx).